How to change color of method after dot in Visual Studio 2022 C# editor?
The main problem is how to change a color of method after dot, when I use it via an interface:
namespace Example
{
    public class ExampleService : IExampleService
    {
        public const string DOCUMENT_TYPE = "PK";

        readonly private IExampleRepository _exampleRepository;

        public CheckoutDocumentService(IExampleRepository exampleRepository)
        {
            _exampleRepository = exampleRepository;
        }

        public void Method() <--- here color work good
        {
            var test = _exampleRepository.ToDoMethod();
        }
    }
}


ToDoMethod is in white color instead of blue aka method,



IExampleRepository is in white color instead of yellow aka interface



real example:






I'm using night owl theme.

User types refer to the class, not an instance of the class. Otherwise IExampleRepository exampleRepository would need to be coloured yellow for both IExampleRepository and exampleRepository. You can however change colouring of fields, which would apply to _exampleRepository, but not to the parameter exampleRepository .

field option dosent changeIExampleRepository  but variable in methods - lol :), I checked build in dark theme from vs and it looks like, night owl has the same settings on those user types and user members properties, meaby something overwrite those colors in the other places?

IExampleRepository is a type, not a variable. So it's of course not affected by field option. _exampleRepository on the other hand is a variable.

IExampleRepository as you can see at attached images it should be yellow, but its white too

Could i confirm with you that have you declared IExampleRepository  in your code? Here is my test result in VS2022.

yes in your test the all lines where interface is used are correct, but you are using a default dark theme, not a night owl theme. In night owl theme it dosent work like in dark theme, but it should.

Did you install any third-party  theme extensions?
I tested night owl theme with Night Owl extension installed and the color works fine.

If you install a third-party theme extension that might contain errors or malicious code, it may effect color display.
I suggest you report the issue of extension you have installed  from here :Visual Studio Marketplace. The author may contact with you.
For example:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=God0nlyKnows.NightOwl&ssr=false#qna
Hope it can help you.

yeah probably I have to, I just to some test and it occurs that I had different version of Nigh Owl (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Defined-Risk.22hrOwl). Then I uninstal it and instal yours, and now in 2019 version work as it should, and in 2022 I still have the issue.

Please try to reset Visual Studio 2022 Settings  and then reload your project. Besides if the issue persists, please consider repairing/uninstalling and reinstalling your VS2022.
